# Rmarkdown and semi-transparency

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, sweave

I had some semi-transparency problem in the past, I solved them by adding this lines in my .Rprofile:

```
setHook(packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"),
                function(...) grDevices::X11.options(type='cairo'))
options(device='x11')
```

So everything is working perfectly in RStudio right now. But when I use the render function in Rmarkdown to produce .html file I get this error again:

> In grid.Call.graphics(L_polygon, x$x, x$y, index) :
>   semi-transparency is not supported on this device: reported only once
>   per page

I tried to plot in the png() device directly in RStudio and get the same error.

So I tried this instead:

```
ggsave("image.png", device = Cairo_png)
```

Using the cairoDevice library: it works!

I tried to force knitr to use Cairo_png as a device. Since I followed the documentation, it should be the correct way to do it. In my Makefile:

```
$(MAINDIR)/%.html:%.Rmd
        Rscript \
                -e "require(rmarkdown); require(knitr); require(cairoDevice)" \
                -e "knitr::opts_chunk[['set']](dev = Cairo_png)" \
                -e "knitr::opts_chunk[['set']](fig.width = 12)" \
                -e "knitr::opts_chunk[['set']](warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, cache = 2)" \
                -e "rmarkdown::render('$<', html_document(), output_dir = '$(MAINDIR)', intermediates_dir = '$(MAINDIR)')"
```

But rmarkdown doesn't seem to use Cairo_png as a device since I still get the same warning.

So I have two problems and I need to solve only one of them: 1- the png() device doesn't support semi-transparency, why ? 2- I can't force rmarkdown to use Cairo_png (which supports the semi-transparency).

Comment: Have you tried [building R from source](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Building-from-source)? If yes, what is the configure script output?

Comment: After compiling from the source... It's workings. Thanks!